# How to trim my home url on the localhost

Tags: php, localhost

This is how I get my url on my localhost:

```
 $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    echo $url;
```

it returns : http://localhost/CodeSensei/menu because I am on the menu page.

How can I trim this? I only want "http://localhost/CodeSensei"

I know I can trim it like this

```
echo trim($url,"menu");
```

But the problem is, that "menu" is dynamic, it keep changing dependes on the page. Is there any way to trim my url so it will always and only print "http://localhost/CodeSensei" in any page?

Comment: Are you saying this "http://localhost/CodeSensei" part of your URL is static? If so why do you need to do anything. If you know its going to be the same, store it in a variable and use it right?

Comment: Not static, its also dynamic, the `$url` variable is dynamic.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_my url_"?

Comment: @kerbholz , I mean, I want to trim the `$url` variable, as you can see  the `$url` variable it output this `http://localhost/CodeSensei/menu` since Im on the menu.php page, But I only want to keep and output the `http://localhost/CodeSensei`

Comment: You want to remove the string after the last '/'. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes @RedBottle , thats right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. You can play around with different string manipulators like [explode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) etc.

Here is a solution using `explode()`

```
$variable =  "http://localhost/CodeSensei/menu";
$variable = (explode("/",$variable));
$url='';

for($i=2;$i<count($variable)-1;$i++)
{  
    $url .= "/".$variable[$i];
}

$final_url = "http:/".$url;

echo $final_url;
```

Your output

```
http://localhost/CodeSensei
```

Answer (score 0):

This function may help you. It get a url and return the url without after the last `/`.

```
<?php
function getSubUrl($originUrl) {
    $url = parse_url($originUrl);
    $url['scheme'] .= '://';
    $url['path'] = dirname($url['path']);

    return implode($url);
}


echo getSubUrl('http://localhost/CodeSensei/menu/123') . PHP_EOL;
// http://localhost/CodeSensei/menu
echo getSubUrl('http://localhost/CodeSensei/menu') . PHP_EOL;
// http://localhost/CodeSensei
echo getSubUrl('http://localhost/CodeSensei') . PHP_EOL;
// http://localhost/
echo getSubUrl('http://localhost/') . PHP_EOL; 
// http://localhost/
echo getSubUrl('http://localhost') . PHP_EOL;
// http://localhost
```